# INSERT INTO Access database from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, insert, pyodbc

Please could somebody tell me how should look like insert into the database but of the all data frame in python?

I found this but don't know how to insert all data frame called test_data with two figures: ID, Employee_id.

I also don't know how to insert the next value for ID (something like nextval)

Thank you

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\test_database.mdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()  
cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO employee_table (ID, employee_id)
                VALUES(?????????)
              ''')
conn.commit()
```

Comment: You may want to use [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). What you are doing now is executing SQL to add values manually with your cursor. There is no need for a cursor with `to_sql`, only a connection to your database.

Comment: How are you planning to insert the entire dataframe without iteration? better search for `to_sql` method for pandas dataframe which can be very helpful in such cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update, June 2020:

Now that the [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) dialect has been revived the best solution would be to use pandas' `to_sql` method.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

---

*(previous answer)*

You can use pyodbc's `executemany` method, passing the rows using pandas' `itertuples` method:

```python
print(pyodbc.version)  ## 4.0.24 (not 4.0.25, which has a known issue with Access ODBC)
connection_string = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public\MyTest.accdb;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

# prepare test environment
table_name = "employee_table"
if list(crsr.tables(table_name)):
    crsr.execute(f"DROP TABLE [{table_name}]")
crsr.execute(f"CREATE TABLE [{table_name}] (ID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, employee_id TEXT(25))")

# test data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'employee1'], [2, 'employee2']], columns=['ID', 'employee_id'])

# insert the rows from the DataFrame into the Access table    
crsr.executemany(
    f"INSERT INTO [{table_name}] (ID, employee_id) VALUES (?, ?)",
    df.itertuples(index=False))
```

**Update:**
Parameterized queries like this work again with pyodbc version 4.0.27 but not 4.0.25 (as mentioned above) or 4.0.26. Attempting to use these versions will result in an "Optional feature not implimented" error. This issue is discussed here https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/509.

Comment: Executemany works awesome. I have only issue to insert values which are Null (empty only some values in rows but they must stay empty). Is there any way how to add parameter to this insert? Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Using `to_sql` you may do :

```
test_data.to_sql('employee_table', engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

This will add the values of the test_data at the end of your employee table.

Comment: This should be the preferred solution now that the [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) dialect has been revived.