# How to insert column headers and data from PANDAS dataframe into MS-Access by PYODBC SQL query

Tags: python, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

I have the following code that manipulates the data and I should insert it into existing table with the same structure. It gives me an error that is in the INSERT query:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "xxxxxx.py", line 50, in <module>
>     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PERPIVOT(", headers, ") values ", (data, ))
> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.(-3502) (SQLPrepare)')
> ```

Here is my code to load dataframe, manipulate it and insert it into existing table that has the same table structure.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas
import os
import sys
import struct

try:
    currdir = os.path.abspath(__file__)
except NameError:  
    import sys
currdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
DBfile = os.path.join(currdir, 'UNION.accdb')
EXPfile = os.path.join(currdir, 'ROLEPIVOT.xlsx')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s;' %DBfile)
sql = "Select * FROM TOPIVOT_CROSSTAB"
df = pandas.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

df = df.set_index('AGR_NAME')
df = df.div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0).round(2)*100

headers = df.columns.values
data = df.values


cursor = cnxn.cursor()

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PERPIVOT(", headers , ") values ", (data, ))

connStr.commit()
cursor.close()
connStr.close()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do `sql = "INSERT INTO PERPIVOT(", headers , ") values ", (data, )` so you can then `print(sql)` and [edit] your question to show the SQL statement you have constructed.

Comment: Hello Mr. Thompson, the print gives me this result: `('INSERT INTO PERPIVOT(', array(['<>', '77', '91', 'CB', 'CC', 'CD', 'CE', 'CF', 'FA', 'FD', 'FX'],
      dtype=object), ') values ', (array([[nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 0., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       ...,
       [ 0., nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, nan],
       [ 0.,  6., nan, ...,  2.,  5., 27.],
       [nan, nan, nan, ..., nan, nan, 68.]]),))`

Comment: Okay, and `type(sql)` probably returns `<class 'tuple'>`, right?

Comment: Yes it does.  `<class 'tuple'>`

Comment: Right, so you're currently creating a `tuple` when it looks like you really want to create a `str`. Also worth noting that inside your `for index,row in df.iterrows():` loop you refer to neither `index` nor `row`; instead you reference `headers` and `values` which are defined outside the loop and therefore will have the same values for every iteration. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54507642/2144390) for a solution to a similar issue.